# How to avoid Expression "changed after checked" error when component changes itself

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular6

I have a dropdown component that needs to handle chrome form filling. In other words it should switch to the item that matches the form filled value.

I have it working but the matching causes the following error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: {
  "name": "Testy McTester",
  "street": "14 15th Street",
  "city": "Cornfield",
  "state": ""
}'. Current value: 'null: {
  "name": "Testy McTester",
  "street": "14 15th Street",
  "city": "Cornfield",
  "state": "KS"
}'.
```

Example Code Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-fill-dropdown

The problem is in this section:

```js
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  // Formfilling may have put a value into the input
  const nativeValue = this.inputField && this.inputField.nativeElement && this.inputField.nativeElement.value;
  if (nativeValue !== this.value) {
    const matchingOption = this.allStates.find(opts => opts && (opts.abbr === nativeValue || opts.name === nativeValue));
    if (matchingOption) {
      // This causes Changed after Checked Error
      this.writeValue(matchingOption.abbr);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

What is the recommended way to let Angular know that the component has changed itself and it needs to run another pass after the change?

Moving `this.writeValue(matchingOption.abbr);` inside a setTimeout() works but seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Try to inject `private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef` to `constructor()` and call 
`this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` behind 
`this.writeValue(matchingOption.abbr);`.

Comment: The error doesn't pop up on stackblitz.

Comment: The error shows up on stackblitz when you initiate a form fill. Let chrome fill in the values and then tab to the next field. You need to have the console open to see it. @JosefKatič I tried changeDetectorRef and got the same behavior. I believe it is it is interrupting a change detection that is already in process.

Comment: I am still not able to reproduce it. You said that I have to switch to that dropdown by tab?

Comment: In the Name field start typing a name so that chrome form filling will pop up suggesting to fill the name and the rest of the address information. Allow chrome to complete the form filling and then tab to the next field. That is when the error will come up.

Answer (score 0):

So you should not call `writeValue` inside `ngAfterViewChecked`. And from your comment you know it is the cause of `Change after checked` error.

what you can do is using a setter:

```
 set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
  }
```

To let Angular know that the component has changed itself, you can use a 2-way binding on that **value** variable in your customized dropdown component.
like:

```
 <input #input [id]="controlId" [(ngModel)]="value" type="text" style="border:none; outline:none"/>
```

Now it seems working.
Check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-fill-dropdown-2dzzzr

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The biggest problem with that approach is that ngModel is deprecated in Angular 6 and will be removed in Angular 7. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel. One other problem is that I believe using the 2-way binding (banana in a box) syntax causes angular to fallback to polling 60x a second for changes instead of responding to change notification.

Comment: The use of mixing ngModel with reactive form is deprecated, but the use of ngModel as template driven form is not.  Anyway, if you do not like ngModel, you can create a  reactive FormControl for this input. they both serve the purpose of letting it know that input value is changed.

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a reactive FormControl inside the custom component that is hosted in a Reactive Form? That seems odd.

Comment: Not at all.  A component encapsulates its internal implementation details. Where you decide to host it should not be a concern.